# asp.net Repeater Databind code behind in MVC5

Tags: repeater

I have a code written in asp.net web forms with lots of repeater Databind and I am trying to rewrite it to MVC 5 EF 6 using Repository Patterns.  I know I cannot use the repeater in MVC, but how can I rewrite the code below in MVC

private void GroupList(Repeater rpt, int DtID, int GroupID, string conNumber, string conName)
        {
            try
            {

```
            var list = data.List<CtItem>.Where(c.CNumber == conNumber && c.Name == conName) 

                       .OrderBy(o => o.CNumber)


            rpt.DataSource = list;
            rpt.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Add `list` to your model and use it in your view to build output.  You *probably* want to start with some introductory tutorials on ASP.NET MVC.  When doing so, *completely forget* everything you know about WebForms.  The skill set doesn't carry over.  If you try to write MVC projects "in a WebForms way" then you're going to end up with *terrible* code and *nothing* you find online for either framework is going to look familiar or helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your `list` variable is going to contain the data you need, then presumably you're fetching that in your controller.  Which you would then add to your model.  It might look something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var list = data.List<CtItem>
                   .Where(c.CNumber == conNumber && c.Name == conName)
                   .OrderBy(o => o.CNumber);
    return View(list);
}
```

In that case, the data type of `list` would *be* the model for your view.  If there's other data that needs to go to the view as well, then it might instead only be a property on a custom view model.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var list = data.List<CtItem>
                   .Where(c.CNumber == conNumber && c.Name == conName)
                   .OrderBy(o => o.CNumber);
    var viewModel = new SomeViewModel();
    viewModel.SomeProperty = list;
    // set other values on the view model
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then in your view you would construct your markup based on the values on the model.  Presumably your grid was generating a `<table>` of some sort.  So constructing the output might look something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column Heading</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model.SomeProperty)
  {
    <th>
      <td>@item.SomeColumnValue</td>
    </th>
  }
</table>
```

Naturally, this has only one column.  You'd expand for whatever your structure needs to be.  You may also derive column headings from meta-data, etc.  There are lots of complexities you *can* add.  But the overall point is that what it sounds like you're trying to do is get data from a data source, send it to the view, and display it in the view.